# Is the Durable Consumer ActiveMQ test case, C# implementation invalid?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, apache-nms

I've been having difficulty getting durable consumers working with ActiveMQ in a C# and Windows environment (works fine in Java).

So I looked at the test case and was shocked to see the test uses the same connection and session to run both the consumer and the producer. No surprise the test passes. But if you separate the consumer and producer into separate processes the test **fails**.

The test code is found in file `csharp_api/DurableTest.cs`

Anyone have any luck getting persistence working using the C# API? How?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your code, no one here can see your screen